# Out-dated NON-HTTPS pages..?

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

Quick question..

I believe this has to do with previously-cached versions of my website that I have stored on my browser..

but when I type in my website URL (answers.legal) with no www... I get an outdated version of my website (i.e. new programming that I have done throughout the day is not showing).

However, when I click on the logo (which redirects to a the HTTPS WWW URL), the current version loads.

How come when I simply type "answers.legal" into the search bar does it not redirect to HTTPS WWW automatically?

Comment: I don't see a difference in the sites and don't know what could cause it. But did you think about simply redirecting one to the other? (eg like [this](http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/), just one of the first hits on my favourite search engine)

Comment: I have read a lot about .htaccess... but I have never seen or touched any type of file named that since my start of developing this website..

How do I go about creating one?

Comment: Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://[your domain name]%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Coincedentally, I actually had that code copied to my clipboard ready to be used when I found my .htaccess file which is a mystery.